# Is it possible to add a map marker by touching the map in Android V2 maps API?

Tags: android, android-maps

I just want to touch the screen, use a listener to detect and add a marker at the location touched and allow the user to add written information to the marker. I done this a while back using the now deprecated API, after a long time searching SO, all I see on markers and V2 API is how to animate, add custom markers, or shadows, all beyond what I need to know. I read through the documentation at Google for a good while and got lost.

It seems that basic stuff is hard to find. I would just like to know if this is possible, and a few pointers on how it is different in V2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would just like to know if this is possible

I don't see why not.

> and a few pointers on how it is different in V2

Implement an `OnMapClickListener` and attach it to your `GoogleMap` via `setOnMapClickListener()`. Your `onMapClick()` method will be called when the user taps on the map. There, add a new marker. AFAIK, this should work just fine.